# Can I tell SqlMetal to not add INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: sql-server-ce, sqlmetal

I'm currently using [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) to generate a data context for a SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 database.

This database will be used in a Windows Phone 7 application, and will only be read from. For this reason I'd like to skip the logic to track property changes (implementing INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged), since the database won't be changed by the user/system.

Is there any way I can tell SqlMetal to exclude this extra logic?

Alternatively, short of creating the context and classes myself, are there any relatively simple changes I can make to improve performance if I left the generated file (mostly) as-is?

Comment: The code that invokes these methods will never be called, if you only read from the database, so there is no performance penalty

Comment: Thanks @EricEJ. Want to post that as an answer so you're credited appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that invokes these methods will never be called, if you only read from the database, so there is no performance penalty